# SetNamedSecurityInfo throwing error code 87

Tags: winapi, windows-server, windows-server-2019

We have been facing this issue for several months.

While using the Windows API function `SetNamedSecurityInfo()`, the error code 87 is returned. I have tried to fix it, but couldn't. Please help me fix this.

```cpp
LPWSTR shareName = (LPWSTR)L"//TEST/test";  
DWORD dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(shareName, SE_FILE_OBJECT, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {       
    cout << "Error while setting SACL in SetNamedSecurityInfo Error  " << dwRes << endl;        
    return -1;  
}
```

We are passing only the `shareName` as a parameter, and all the remaining parameters are constant.

Normally this code should function without setting any SACL permissions, and without any errors.

But, this is returning error 87, which means "**The parameter is incorrect**". But the only parameter that has been passed is the `shareName`, and if the `shareName` is wrong then the function should return error 67 instead, which means "**The network name cannot be found**".

Why is error 87 being returned in this case?

Comment: Why do you use //TEST/test instead of \\TEST\test? Also if it's a file on a share, it should be \\TEST\test\somefile

Comment: We have already tried with both slashes, but still same issue. Also it is a folder to be shared not a file.

Comment: folder or file requires the same format for SE_FILE_OBJECT, it cannot be only \\TEST\test

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` flag, but you are setting the `pSACL` parameter to `NULL`.  That is why you are getting the `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (87) error.  When the `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` flag is used, the `pSACL` parameter must point to a valid `SACL` object.